Do I need to have a real service for the AWS SES custom FROM domain?
Say I have setup an SES domain (identity) called example.com. It seems advisable (for best deliverability) to create a custom FROM domain. This must be a subdomain of the main domain (according to SES), so say I choose notifications.example.com.
When I do that and then send test emails to some validation tools, they complain that there is no DNS A record for notifications.example.com. Is that really necessary? Is there actually supposed to be some service/listener at notifications.example.com?
Thanks.

You need to verify the custom MAIL FROM and add records to your DNS. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/mail-from.html#mail-from-set

Hi Tsal. Yes, I've done all that. What I'm unsure about is this statement: "SES requires you to publish an MX record so that your domain can receive the bounce and complaint notifications that email providers send you". Does this mean that there must be a mailbox or some service at notifications.example.com to receive these notifications?

You will need to create records for the Custom MAIL FROM domain, such as:
MX | notifications.example.com | 10 feedback-smtp.<region>.amazonses.com
TXT | notifications.example.com | "v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all"

As stated in the link here about Custom MAIL FROM Domains in SES
Although to your question, you do not need an A record (for the notifications.example.com domain) in order to use Amazon SES in this intended way. Email validation tools may complain about needing certain records although they may not understand the use case.
I hope this information helps! :)
